# Accessing a promise with the componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, promise

I'm accessing a promise that gets returned from my mock API. The React component looks like what you see below

```
import React from 'react';
import StudentListStatistics from './StudentListStatistics';
import StudentStatisticsApi from '../../api/mockStudentApi';

class AboutPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);
      this.state = {
          studentsStatistics: []
      };

  }

componentDidMount() {
    StudentStatisticsApi.getAllStudentsStatistics().then(
        studentsStatistics => {
            this.setState({
                studentsStatistics: studentsStatistics

            });
            debugger;
        }
    );

    console.log(this.state.studentsStatistics);
}

render() {
    return (
        <div>
            <h2>Student Body Statistics</h2>
            <StudentListStatistics studentsStatistics={this.state.studentsStatistics}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

the mock API looks like this

```
class StudentApi {
static getAllStudentsStatistics() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject)=> {
        setTimeout(()=> {
            resolve(Object.assign([], studentsStatistics));
        }, 1000);
    });
}
```

I'm not sure why the this.state.studentsStatistics is always an empty array. If I step through the code then studentsStatistics array is being returned correctly from my mock API within the then callback.

Can someone point out what I might be missing.

Comment: Do you mean that the `console.log()` always shows an empty array? Or is nothing being rendered either?

Comment: console.log() shows [] - the render is fine - <StudentListStatistics studentsStatistics={this.state.studentsStatistics}/> component shows an warning as expected since an empty array is being passed to the StudentListStatistics component which is to be expected. I have PropType validation set as required in the StudentListStatistics component so I get the following warning "Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `studentBodyStatistics` was not specified in `StudentStatisticsRow`. Check the render method of `StudentListStatistics`."

Comment: That the `console.log` shows an empty array makes sense, but I would think that (eventually) your `StudentListStatistics` would render the mocked data (initially it _would_ receive an empty array because that's the initial state of your component).

Comment: But once ComponentDidMount is triggered then the console.log should show the data being returned. I agree that initially it would be an empty array but even after the componentDidMount is triggered a [] is being returned

Comment: Don't use `self = this` if you're using arrow functions (`=>`) since those have lexical `this` scope. Don't mix delaying a promise and having logic in it - instead build a `delay` primitive and use that. You don't need to repeat object properties in literals, `{ studentsStatistics:studentsStatistics }` is just `{studentsStatistics}`. Don't use `debugger`, use breakpoints in the developer tools (forgetting a debugger in your code de-optimizes your code)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum I'm coming up to speed with ReactJs/Redux so have debugger sprinkled librarily through my code but I have Linter setup which warns me Unexcepted 'debugger' statement. That's correct, I should not be repeating object properties in literals but was being explicit since as I mentioned before I'm learning ReactJs/Redux. I was delaying the promise while grabbing data from my mockApi to potentially mimic what might happen if I call an actual server side web API and was looking to have a spinning wheel. Self = this I've been kicking my self for this and should have edited question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is two-fold:

- `getAllStudentsStatistics()` is asynchronous, which means that it will *eventually* yield a result, but not immediately;
- `setState()` is also "asynchronous", in that it won't change `this.state` immediately after it got called.

To work around that, and log the mocked data, you need to first wait for the promise to resolve, and then to also wait for `setState` to acknowledge that the state has changed (by [passing it a callback function](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate)):

```
componentDidMount() {
  let promise = StudentStatisticsApi.getAllStudentsStatistics();

  promise.then(studentsStatistics => {
    this.setState({
      studentsStatistics: studentsStatistics
    }, () => {
      console.log(this.state.studentsStatistics);
    }
  });
}
```

I think this also means that your `StudentListStatistics` component will initially be rendered with an empty array as input. Only once the promise has been resolved will it receive the mocked data.

Comment: thanks, makes sense, once quick followup question - I'm still getting the warning.js?8a56:44Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `studentBodyStatistics` was not specified in `StudentStatisticsRow`. Check the render method of `StudentListStatistics`. Should the render method not "re-render" based on the fact that the state has been updated?

Comment: @usr28765526 it sounds like there's something else going wrong, perhaps in your property declaration. Do you pass a property called `studentBodyStatistics` to your `StudentStatisticsRow` components?

Comment: yea - I just figured that out ... - it works perfectly now - frustrating I couldn't figure the callback issue staring at me. thanks again